# Creating a copy of a collection

Tags: java, list, collections, copy

I'm reading J. Bloch's effective Java and now I'm at the section about avoiding returning `null`s, but returning empty collections. This's the code example form the section:

```
// The right way to return a copy of a collection
public List<Cheese> getCheeseList() {
  if (cheesesInStock.isEmpty())
    return Collections.emptyList(); // Always returns same list
  else
    return new ArrayList<Cheese>(cheesesInStock);
}
```

I really cannot understand what's wrong with just returning the `cheesesInStock` if `cheesesInStock.isEmpty()`. why is it better to return the predefined `Collections.emptyList()`. What kind of troubles we may get into, if we return `cheesesInStock` instead.

Comment: The method is commented _"// The right way to return a **copy** of a collection"_. What do you think `return cheesesInStock;` does ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the method returns `cheesesInStock` - the caller may add some cheese to the list.

It is a bad practice as you may want to control adding procedure.

Answer (score 5):

Because

- you will save resources with `Collections.emptyList();` that has a singletton pattern.
- it's type-safe
- list is immutable (cannot be modified)

Also taking a [look at the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29) you can find:

> Returns the **empty list (immutable)**. This list is serializable.
>
> This example illustrates the type-safe way to obtain an empty list:

```
 List<String> s = Collections.emptyList();
```

> **Implementation note:** Implementations of this method need not create a separate List object for each call. **Using this method is likely to have comparable cost to using the like-named field. (Unlike this method, the field does not provide type safety.)**

Answer (score 5):

The idea here is more about safe object publication or sharing, returning a reference to a mutable list allows the caller to mutate the original list which is usually a bad idea. If the list or the object in general is immutable then you don't need to do that, String for example is immutable and hence sharing it is safe.

```
String getString(){
  return someString; // no need to copy
}
```

Shared mutable state comes with two main headaches:

1. Its hard to check program's correctness when things can be mutated from anywhere.
2. Thread safety becomes harder because it requires synchronisation which is usually hard and expensive.

Answer (score 2):

If you return `cheesesInStock` directly, you return a reference to the same `List` that the one you're object is having (and not a copy of it); so any changes made by someone acquiring this list will reflect in the internal representation of the object. Example:

```
List<Cheese> list = myObject.getCheeseList();
list.add(new Cheese()); // this also affects the list inside myObject
```

To prevent from this, it is a good practice to return a copy of the list instead with `new ArrayList<Cheese>(previousList)`. Note that instead of returning a new `List`, you could also return an unmodifiable view of the `List`, using [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-): this has the same goal - prevent a calling code to modify the internal representation of the object.

The advantage of returning `Collections.emptyList();` instead of returning `new ArrayList<Cheese>(emptyList)` is that you avoid the creation of another object. Also, `Collections.emptyList();` represents an immutable `List`.

Answer (score 2):

The `cheesesInStock` List can be structurally modified later but a  `Collections.emptyList()` returns an empty list which cannot be structrally modified later.`Collections.emptyList()` returns `EmptyList` ,some of the functions are :-

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
public E get(int index) {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: "+index);
}
```